# How can I get `less` (or another pager) to show a full line without paginating it if it starts with certain characters?

Tags: git, iterm2

I use iTerm2 on Mac, and it has a cool `imgcat` command that lets you display images in the terminal. I'm trying to set this up with `git diff` so I can see visual diffs whenever an image changes.

I got this working by adding the following to `~/.config/git/attributes`:

```
*.png  diff=image
*.jpg  diff=image
*.gif  diff=image
*.jpeg diff=image
```

And to `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[diff "image"]
    textconv = imgcat
    command = 'imgdiff'
```

(Using an `imgdiff` script from here: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/n44hnf0z99-show-better-image-diff-on-git)

I had to turn off the pager in my `~/.gitconfig` to get this to work properly:

```
[pager]
    diff = false
```

Otherwise the pager breaks the image protocol and just shows a bunch of encoded characters for large images. E.g.

```
file=inline=1;size=104891:iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAADxgAAAPwCAIAAAA3Et0bAAAAIGNIUk0AAHomAACAhAAA+gAAAIDoAAB1MAAA6mAAADqYAAAXcJy6UTwAAAAGYktHRAD/AP8A/6C9p5MAAIAASURBVHja7N13nFxV3fjx7y3TZ2dme8mmk9BDEhKKUgWREhABBaQooqCiyKOoD8LzKPJTUPTBig0LYq+oNBFQkRZagIQW0rO9z06f235/3GSZbJlMkt1Mkvm8X7x09sy553zvnbx258z3O+cqjuMIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFQStdwBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMDuRiE1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgIpDITUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAiqMX/pDOmuWOB0B5OI7jOI7tOPHBgemtzeUOBwCAHba5rTNaXaMqW5Q7HABlYObTpXeORCLjttu2U+7zAFBOjohlml...
```

If I have a large `git diff` then this becomes annoying.

The iTerm2 inline images protocol uses some escape characters to tell the terminal that it should render an image, e.g. `ESC ] 1337 ; key = value ^G`
See: https://iterm2.com/documentation-images.html

My question: Can I get the `less` pager to ignore lines that start with this character sequence, and get it to print these lines in full? I still want to use the pager for text content, but I want the pager to print any image data in full, since iTerm2 will convert it into an image.

Or is it not possible to use a pager with this inline image rendering?